# How is it possible to make a chrome extension with rounded borders like Klarna's?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, border-radius

I know that by default, the chrome extension popups can't have rounded borders but some do like the Klarna Chrome Extension. Not only does the extension have rounded borders, it also has a box-shadow around it and is draggable within the window. I am currently creating a chrome extension and want to achieve a similar look to this with the shape of my extension. [Screenshot of Klarna's Chrome Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3XeI.png)

I have tried giving the giving the window a border radius but it looks nothing like Klarna's.[Screenhot of my Chrome Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLF3H.png)

Comment: This is a DOM element., not the `action` popup. You can do the same in your content script.